# Developer Dashboard Bug. No OAuth token for packaged app

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

Seriously, how do I do this?  I've looked and Googled for two days, and it's not there.

I'm trying to sell an app through the Google Web Store.  It is a packaged off-line app, with a custom server backend.

I think to do this I need the Licensing API, and that says I need an OAuth Token.  I'm following these [instructions](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started#oauth) to get the token.

Here are [screenshots](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/aew3ecswgsmra2k/AABT1MzAHQteqTTgaztUagjRa?dl=0) of my view of the Chrome App in the Developer Dashboard.  My app's id is: lhhdccfgjpdaidjegbioednlnlidefno

- I figured out app needs to be "public" to get the "Change Pricing"
  button.  Ok.  Changed it to Chrome Web Store Payments.
- After setting the pricing to Chrome Web Store Payments, I publish the app publicly,
  but no OAuth token link appears.  I don't see an option for this in
  any of the UI.

How do I use the Licensing API with a packaged app?

Please help!

Mike

Comment: Have you clicked "More Info"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks everyone who read/answered this.  The missing piece was here:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity

Chrome has a browser API to call to get the token.  There is no need to get it from the Developer Dashboard, hence I couldn't find it.  I think much of the documentation is out of date and written before Chrome had the browser API for this.

This URL is likely a good example even for subscriptions.  https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments

Thanks for your help!

Mike

Comment: Can you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045344/getting-an-oauth-access-token-to-work-for-chrome-extension